# Do I need to use Invoke when calling async method with Task.Run?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with one of the events from a DLL, and I've decided to move some code to a separate Sub and make that call async (with a delay):

```
Public Async Sub DeskoScan()


  ListAdd("Perform scan START.")
  Try

    If _Duplex AndAlso _firstImageFileUploaded Then
      Await Task.Delay(1000) ' here I want to be sure that all things related to the previous scanning process are closed
      Dim Aborted As Boolean
      Using frm = New countingForm
        frm.lblTime.Text = _My_Settings.Item("WaitForDialog").Value
        frm.lblMessage.Text = "Flip Document For Second Page Scan" _
                  + vbCrLf + " - press OK when ready, or wait for count down to 0" _
                  + vbCrLf + " - press Retry for another " + _My_Settings.Item("WaitForDialog").Value + " seconds" _
                  + vbCrLf + " - press Abort to just cancel it"

        frm.btnRetry.DialogResult = DialogResult.None
        Aborted = frm.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.Abort
      End Using

      If Aborted Then
        Exit Sub
      End If
    End If

    _deviceThread.Execute(Sub(ByVal device As Desko.Scan.Device)
                            device.Snapshot.Reset()
                            device.Snapshot.Infrared.Enabled = False
                            device.Snapshot.Infrared.Flags = Desko.Scan.ScanFlags.None
                            device.Snapshot.Infrared.ShutterWidthFactor = 1
                            device.Snapshot.Visible.Enabled = True
                            device.Snapshot.Visible.Flags = Desko.Scan.ScanFlags.DocumentClipping Or Desko.Scan.ScanFlags.AmbientFilter
                            device.Snapshot.Visible.ShutterWidthFactor = 1
                            device.Snapshot.Ultraviolet.Enabled = False
                            device.Snapshot.Ultraviolet.Flags = Desko.Scan.ScanFlags.None
                            device.Snapshot.Ultraviolet.ShutterWidthFactor = 1
                            device.Snapshot.Resolution = Desko.Scan.Resolution.Full
                            device.Snapshot.Perform()
                          End Sub)

  Catch ex As Exception
    ListAdd(ex.ToString())
  End Try
End Sub
```

And because the procedure is run in a separate thread apart from the main one, I call it like this:

```
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
      Me.Invoke(Sub() DeskoScan())
    Else
      DeskoScan()
    End If
```

Now in that event, I want to call that code but to make an async call, like this:

```
Private Sub HandleSnapshotCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Desko.Scan.SnapshotCompletedEventArgs)

  If _Duplex AndAlso _firstImageFileUploaded Then

    Task.Run(Sub() DeskoScan()) 'Is this enough or do I need Me.Invoke too?

  Else
    ListAdd("Snapshot completed. You may remove the document.")
    Minimize()
  End If

End Sub
```

My question is do I need here Invoke call or Task.Run is enough? (I can't test this code because I am missing a scanner)

**UPDATE**

Yes Craig you are right I don't need Task.Run here, but I need async await Sub so I can make sure that all event handlers on scanner objects are processed. By doing Await Task.Delay(2000) I will make the Sub asynchronous.

```
  Public Async Sub DeskoScan()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
      Me.Invoke(Sub() DeskoScan())
    Else
      Await Task.Delay(2000)
      ....
    End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do `Task.Run` on it, since it already is pushing things off into a thread itself.  You should change it from `Async Sub` to `Async Function ... As Task`; `Async Sub` is really only intended to be used by event handlers (like your `HandleSnapshotCompleted`), then you can `Await` the result.  I'd highly recommend reading everything Stephen Cleary has written on async programming before you go any further.

Comment: I will repeat, you should change `DeskoScan` from `Async Sub DeskoScan` to `Async Function DeskoScan As Task`.  The body will remain the same, but callers will call using `Await DeskoScan`.  `Async Sub` is really only intended to be used by event handlers.  Again, read everything Stephen Cleary has written on async programming before you go any further.

Comment: @Craig thanks for all suggestions I appreciate them, I made much progress by delaying running that sub it worked!

Answer (score 1):

A **SWAG** because it is not clear what you are doing...

```
Private Async Sub DeskoScanTsk()
    Dim tsk As Task
    tsk = Task.Run(Sub() DeskoScan())
    Await tsk
End Sub

Private Sub HandleSnapshotCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Desko.Scan.SnapshotCompletedEventArgs)

    If _Duplex AndAlso _firstImageFileUploaded Then

        DeskoScanTsk()

    Else
        ListAdd("Snapshot completed. You may remove the document.")
        Minimize()
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub DeskoScan()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(Sub() DeskoScan())
    Else
        ListAdd("Perform scan START.")
        Try

            If _Duplex AndAlso _firstImageFileUploaded Then
                Dim Aborted As Boolean
                Using frm = New countingForm
                    frm.lblTime.Text = _My_Settings.Item("WaitForDialog").Value
                    frm.lblMessage.Text = "Flip Document For Second Page Scan" _
                              + vbCrLf + " - press OK when ready, or wait for count down to 0" _
                              + vbCrLf + " - press Retry for another " + _My_Settings.Item("WaitForDialog").Value + " seconds" _
                              + vbCrLf + " - press Abort to just cancel it"

                    frm.btnRetry.DialogResult = DialogResult.None
                    Aborted = frm.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.Abort
                End Using

                If Aborted Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If

            _deviceThread.Execute(Sub(device As Desko.Scan.Device)
                                      device.Snapshot.Reset()
                                      device.Snapshot.Infrared.Enabled = False
                                      device.Snapshot.Infrared.Flags = Desko.Scan.ScanFlags.None
                                      device.Snapshot.Infrared.ShutterWidthFactor = 1
                                      device.Snapshot.Visible.Enabled = True
                                      device.Snapshot.Visible.Flags = Desko.Scan.ScanFlags.DocumentClipping Or Desko.Scan.ScanFlags.AmbientFilter
                                      device.Snapshot.Visible.ShutterWidthFactor = 1
                                      device.Snapshot.Ultraviolet.Enabled = False
                                      device.Snapshot.Ultraviolet.Flags = Desko.Scan.ScanFlags.None
                                      device.Snapshot.Ultraviolet.ShutterWidthFactor = 1
                                      device.Snapshot.Resolution = Desko.Scan.Resolution.Full
                                      device.Snapshot.Perform()
                                  End Sub)

        Catch ex As Exception
            ListAdd(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When the first scan is finished then HandleSnapshotCompleted is raised which I believe is the last event of Desko scanner scanning process. And then I have to repeat the scan once again after 10 seconds which I do, but then everything freezes. So my best guess is that I need more time after that event to run it again, which one I try to accomplish by running that sub async with a delay of 1 second.